# Zip file created but not downloaded MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax, dotnetzip

In my view i have some checkboxes and their values include a Uri.
In the controller i get the values of the checked checkboxes, download their content (text) and zip them.

It looks like that the zip file is created but when i am trying to download it never works.
I do not get any error. even more worse i get Status 200.

AJAX in View.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#GetTotal').on('click', function () {
        var prices = [];
        $('input[name="check[]"]:checked').each(function () {

            prices.push($(this).attr("value"));
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AzureSearchService/DownloadAll",
            type: "GET",
            data: { coursePrices: prices },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            success: function () {
                alert("ajax request to server succeed");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="@url" class="checkbox1" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult DownloadAll(IEnumerable<Uri> coursePrices)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (Uri uri in coursePrices)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            Stream s = wc.OpenRead(uri);
            zip.AddEntry(uri.AbsolutePath +  ".txt", s);                 
        }

        zip.Save(outputStream);
    }

    outputStream.Position = 0;
    return File(outputStream, "application/zip", "all.zip");
}
```

**Please find below the status by the browser**
[What Browser Returns Status 200](http://postimg.org/image/w5v072tel/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to download files from an ajax call.
It's usually tricky to download files to the client's computer only from javascript. You can consider doing one of the following:

1. Use a third party plugin like jQuery File Download
   http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/
2. You can wrap your checkboxes inside a form like so:
   @using(Html.BeginForm("DownloadAll", "AzureSearchService", /* additional parameters */))

   {

   @* your checkboxes go here *@
   }

Comment: The Ajax call only returns the urls..Then the job is done through the controller

Comment: So you are passing a list of Uris to your controller which sends a request to each of them, saving the results into a txt file and zipping them all together. After all this, you want to download the created zip file to the client computer. Am I right or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Yes you are right. that's what exactly i am trying to do. I do get the uris and everything but the download does not work

Comment: The problem is that the browser does not let you save files to your computer from javascript for security reasons. Try one of my suggested  methods.